# Protractor - is there a way to Do a click/drag event with x,y coordinates

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have diary page with rows (time) and columns(person). I want to drag and select three rows from top to bottom. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [`actions`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions) to perform drag and drop in Protractor, which also includes offset x & y. Something like:

```
browser.actions().
    mouseDown(timeElement, {x: right, y: bottom}).
    mouseMove(personElement, {x: right, y: bottom}).
    mouseUp().
    perform();
```

Comment: Thanks@brine it works. Is there way to drag without element id and only by co ordinates ?

Comment: You can't click outside the browser... but you can likely pass in a `body`, or some outer div on your page, which should be the same thing as you're looking to do.